# What are some simple embarrassingly parallel algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I'm writing a test application for [Cicero](http://www.neptune-lang.org/2011/12/Version-013-Released) and I need a simple embarrassingly parallel algorithm that is easy to understand but slightly less trivial as adding one to the input.

Right now, I'm only interested in algorithms that only require a "map" step. Alternatively, I'm only interested in the "map" step of an algorithm.

Any ideas?

Comment: look at cpi.c:  http://www.usqcd.org/fnal/example/cpi.c

Comment: Interesting question, but too broad, you need to restrain the scope of your question to avoid falling in the "non constructive" category.

Answer (score 2):

An embarrassingly parallel algorithm is one that generally has some data structure D assembled from elements e by some operation o such as concatenate.  You get embarrassing parallelism when you want to apply operations X to D, e.g., compute X(D), and you get it by using a distributive law  X(D)= X(p) O X(q) with D = p o q.    By dividing D into its elements, you can apply X to each one and compute the answers interdependently.

Many matrix operations that apply element-by-element operations (e.g., matrix add, subtract) is embarrassingly parallel.  FORTRAN has an ELEMENTAL function that you can apply to arrays that are intended to be used in such operations.

You can generalize the concatenate operation in N dimensions or gluing operations that compose subgraphs together.